# ¿Es posible escuchar los cambios de varias tablas para actualizar otra tabla en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy creando un control de actualizaciones de varias tablas y a su vez quiero registrar en una tabla llamada `sync_status` todas las tablas que se modificaron con una marca del tiempo.

Esta sería la estructura de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `sync_status` (
  `tableName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `lastUpdate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Ahora, digamos que ocurre un cambio en una tabla llamada `today`. Para tener un control de las actualizaciones ocurridas en `today` he creado una tabla llamada `sync_today`, que está definida así:

```
CREATE TABLE `sync_today` (
  `todayDate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `versionDB` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `crud` char(1) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`todayDate`),
  UNIQUE KEY  (`todayDate`,`versionDB`,`crud`,`lastUpdate`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`todayDate`) REFERENCES `today` (`todayDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Y he programado `TRIGGER` que insertan en `sync_today` una fila con la marca del tiempo y el tipo de evento: `c` si es un `INSERT`, y `u` si es un `UPDATE`:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `today_after_insert`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `today_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `today` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `sync_today` (`todayDate`,`crud`) VALUES(NEW.`todayDate`,'c');
END$$
DELIMITER ;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `today_after_update`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `today_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `today` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE countRows INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sync_today` WHERE `todayDate`=NEW.`todayDate` INTO countRows;
  IF countRows>0 THEN
    UPDATE `sync_today` SET `crud`='u' WHERE `todayDate`=NEW.`todayDate`;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO `sync_today` (`todayDate`,`crud`) VALUES(NEW.`todayDate`,'u');
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Este es el caso de una tabla entre muchas. Mi pregunta es: **¿Hay alguna forma de escuchar cambios en varias tablas, para insertar en `sync_status` el nombre de la tabla y la marca del tiempo de forma automática**?

Mi idea es evitar tener que hacer algo así en cada definición de `TRIGGER`, ya que son varias tablas:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `today_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `today` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `sync_today` (`todayDate`,`crud`) VALUES(NEW.`todayDate`,'c');
    -- ¿Hacer esto de forma genérica?
    INSERT INTO `sync_status` (`tableName`) VALUES ('today');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Y también en:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `today_after_update`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `today_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `today` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE countRows INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sync_today` WHERE `todayDate`=NEW.`todayDate` INTO countRows;
  IF countRows>0 THEN
    UPDATE `sync_today` SET `crud`='u' WHERE `todayDate`=NEW.`todayDate`;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO `sync_today` (`todayDate`,`crud`) VALUES(NEW.`todayDate`,'u');
  END IF;
  -- ¿Hacer esto de forma genérica?
  INSERT INTO `sync_status` (`tableName`) VALUES ('today');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

#### PD

El objetivo de esto es sincronizar una base de datos de Android  con la base de datos remota (que tendrá la versión más actualizada de los datos). Y la idea de `sync_status` es tomar siempre la última fecha de actualización para cada usuario de la App, que tendrá un registro propio de su última actualización. Así, actualizará sólo las tablas que hayan sido modificadas a partir de la fecha que cada uno tenga guardada en su dispositivo.

Parece un trabalenguas, pero si hay alguna otra idea para hacer esto, será bienvenida.

Comment: La primera idea sería crear un procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) genérico que reciba los parámetros necesarios desde los distintos disparadores (triggers) y por medio de una sentencia dinámica hacer la inserción necesaria, pero existe la limitante que desde el contexto de un disparador (trigger) al llamar a un procedimiento almacenado que contenga una consulta dinámica, dicha llamada fallará. Evalue algo como: [MySQL CDC, Streaming Binary Logs, and Asynchronous Triggers](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/09/13/mysql-cdc-streaming-binary-logs-and-asynchronous-triggers/).

Comment: @wchiquito pues me has dado una muy buena idea, lo he implementado y funciona. Cree una SP que haga el `UPDATE`, y le paso como parámetro el nombre de la tabla desde cada `TRIGGER`, no es exactamente lo que quería, pero me parece una forma simple y quizá no tan costosa de hacerlo. Aunque [en esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10663) desaconsejan que se llame a SP desde dentro de los TRIGGER.